# autossh over many LocalForward ports

Tags: ssh

I have to connect to a base server, call it server1, and the from there, I can access many other servers (host1, host2, ...host99.) I have the autossh working for server1 with no problems - it restores my connection to server1 anytime my network connection is lost. However, staying connected to server1 is not my only goal. I want to stay connected to host1, 2, etc. when I'm using those machines.

I just use this to get to server1:

```
autossh server1
```

Right now, when I try to autossh to host1, I get:

```
local autossh[867] <Error>: bind on 127.0.0.1:12346: Address already in use
```

Now, the setting for my monitoring port is just 12345 (in ~/.bash_profile):

```
export AUTOSSH_PORT=12345
```

...so it looks like the localhost port 1234**6** is tried next but fails.

My ~.ssh/config has this forwarding setup:

```
Host server1
  User jacob
  HostName server1.mydomain.com
  Port 722
  ForwardAgent yes
  LocalForward 1124 1:22
  RemoteForward 52698 127.0.0.1:52698 #for sublime text / rmate
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host host1
 User jacob
 HostName localhost
 RemoteForward 52698 127.0.0.1:52698
 Port 1124
 ForwardAgent yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

....I've read everything I could find about the "Address already in use" error and tried modifying my config file, adding hosts to the etc/hosts file, still the same result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `man autossh` (the manual page), with the monitoring port specified in a single number, `autossh` uses both that port and port+1 for its monitoring function, where the latter is called its "echo port" (for receiving the monitoring response). That means it will listen on port+1, and thereby claim that port. A subsequent `autossh` program must be given different ports.

Alternatively you may use port 0, which turns off the connectivity test, and then just restarts `ssh` should it exit. Quoting the manual page:

> Setting the monitor port to 0 turns the monitoring function off, and
>   autossh will only restart ssh upon ssh's exit. For example, if you are
>   using a recent version of OpenSSH, you may wish to explore using the
>   **ServerAliveInterval** and **ServerAliveCountMax** options to have the SSH
>   client exit if it finds itself no longer connected to the server. In
>   many ways this may be a better solution than the monitoring port.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I read that part of the man page and thought the lack of monitoring would kill the intended functionality of reconnecting, but apparently the monitoring feature is distinct from auto-reconnect.